# PHP Form Troubles

Tags: php, forms

I am using 000webhost for my website and they keep suspending my account because I am apparently sending more that 1000 emails. This happens about 30 seconds after submitting an email via my contact form. I am only receiving one email and all emails outbound from the form go to me, they arent in my spam either.

I just wanted an opinion on whether this form is actually looping and sending the message but im not getting them or this is 000webhost fault. I had a contact form since I made this website and its only causing issues now.

Heres the code for the contact form:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/primary.css"> <!--Address Using URL to prevent no styling when slash is typed-->
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Images/tabIcon.ico">
<title>Harry Felton | Welcome</title>
</head>
<script language="php">
    require_once'header.php';
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('body').hide()
    $("#notify").hide()
</script>
<script>
    function toggleAbout(){
        if ($("#center").hasClass("up")) {
            $("#about").slideToggle(500);
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#center").css({
                    msTransform: 'translateY(10px)',
                    webkitTransform: 'translateY(10px)',
                    transform: 'translateY(10px)',
                })
            }, 500);
        } else {
            $("#center").css({
                msTransform: 'translateY(-75px)',
                webkitTransform: 'translateY(-75px)',
                transform: 'translateY(-75px)',
            })      
            setTimeout(function() {
            $("#about").slideToggle(500);
        }, 1000);

        }
        $($("#center").toggleClass("up"))
    };
</script>
<body onunload="" class="pg-index">
    <div class="overwrap">
        <div id="center">
            <h1 id="title1">Welcome</h1>
            <h2 id="title2">Harry Felton</h2>
            <h2 id="subTitle">Auckland | New Zealand</h2>
            <br><br><br><br>
            <div id="about" style="display: none;">
                <p>Hi, My name is Harry and I am an amateur programmer, I just do it as a hobby until I can actually take it as a course, I have created many programs, and love doing it, I am also into ComputerCraft which is a mod for Minecraft that adds programmable computers.<br><br>This website domain was initially created around September 2014, It took about a week to create, It was awesome, As it was the first time I had ever used HTML, CSS or JavaScript. On the 20th November I chose to completely recreate the website, So I deleted all files, And now... Here we are.<br><br>My absolute favorite thing to do in this world is code, I enjoy making, distributing and using my programs, And the feedback is always awesome, If you feel like leaving feedback, then click HERE</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/element.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="JavaScript/pageNav.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"></script>
        <div id="contactForm" class="hidden">
            <title>Contact Us</title>
            <div id="mainPageCont">
            <?php error_reporting(0); ?>
            <?php if(isset($_POST['Email'])): ?>
                <?php
                $to      = 'harryfelton12@gmail.com';
                $subject = 'ALERT! Website Form Submission';
                $message = 'Users Name: '.strip_tags($_POST['Name'])."\n"; 
                $message .= 'Users Email: '.strip_tags($_POST['Email'])."\n";
                $message .= 'Submitted Message: '.strip_tags($_POST['Comment'])."\n";
                $headers = 'From: noReply@harryfelton.com' . "\r\n" .
                    'Reply-To: '.strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n";
                ?>
                <?php if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)): ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    console.log('Mail OK')
                    location.href="/"  
                </script>
                <?php endif ?>
            <?php  else: ?>
            <script>console.log('Loading Contact Script')</script>
            <form method="post" id="comments_form">
                <h2>Please Leave Some Feedback, It Helps!</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label">
                        Your Name
                    </div>
                    <!--.label end-->
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="Name"
                            value="<?php echo isset($_POST['Name'])? $_POST['Name'] : ''; ?>" placeholder="e.g John Doe"/>
                    </div>
                    <!--.input end-->
                    <div class="context">
                        <span>We want to know who we are talking too</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--end .context-->
                </div>
                <!--.row end-->

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label">
                        Your Email
                    </div>
                    <!--.label end-->
                    <div class="input">
                        <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="Email" placeholder="e.g test@example.com" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['Email'])? $_POST['Email'] : ''; ?>" />
                    </div>
                    <!--.input end-->
                    <div class="context">
                        <span>We will send an email to this address containing a confirmation and any further replies</span>
                    </div>
                    <!--end .context-->
                </div>
                <!--.row end-->
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="label">
                        Your Message
                    </div>
                    <!--.label end-->
                    <div class="input2">
                        <textarea id="Comment" name="Comment" class="mess"><?php echo isset($_POST['Comment'])? $_POST['Comment'] : ''; ?></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <!--.input end-->
                </div>
                <!--.row end-->

                <div class="submit">
                    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" value="Send Message" />
                </div>
            </form>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <script>
            function CheckVal() {
                var SetMess = $('#option').val();
                $('#feedback').html(SetMess);

                if (SetMess !== '')  {
                        $('#submit').prop('disabled', false);
                    }
                else {
                        $('#submit').prop('disabled', true);
                    }
            }
            // As one types, check that the message is not empty
            $('#option').keyup(function () {
                CheckVal();
            });
            // As one clicks into the field, see if it has content
            $('#option').click(function () {
                CheckVal();
            });

                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        // validate form
                        $("#comments_form").validate({
                            // This will allow you to extend the validator functions
                            invalidHandler: 
                                    function(form, validator) {
                                      //  $("#get_online").val("CHECK");
                                },
                            rules: {
                                // For every named input that you want to validate,
                                // you create a little set of prefs
                                Name: {
                                    required: true,
                                },
                                Email: {
                                            required: true,
                                            email: true
                                        },
                                Comment: { required: true },
                                },
                            messages: {
                                    // Here are just the custom messages you can modify per field
                                    Name: {
                                            required: 'Please Enter Your Name', 
                                        },
                                    Email: {
                                            required: 'Please Enter An Email',
                                            email: 'Email address not valid',
                                        },
                                    Comment: { required: 'Please Enter A Message'},
                                },
                        });
                    });
            </script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {  
            fadeIn("body");
            setTimeout(function() {
                notification();
            }, 500)
        });
    </script>
<script>changeWelcome("#title1");</script>

    <div id="notify">Disabled JavaScript Is Now Supported, Contact Form Is Being Worked On Again!<a onclick="notification();" id="notifyClose">x</a></div>    
    <script>
        function notification() {
            isNotify = true
            notifyID = "#notify"
            if (isNotify) {
                if ($(notifyID).hasClass("vis")) {
                    console.log("Notification Bar Enabled, Hiding: "+notifyID);
                    $(notifyID).slideUp(500);               
                } else {
                    $(notifyID).slideDown(500);
                    console.log("Notification Bar Enabled, Showing: "+notifyID);
                }
                $(notifyID).toggleClass("vis");
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If you guys wanna visit the webiste then heres the link: http://www.harryfelton.host56.com/ Although it may be offline due to the account being suspended.

So... what do you think, is this loop sending 1000 emails? Ive been doing some console and alert testing and it never seems to send a message more than once, but I thought maybe the pause time had an effect.

Comment: Can you post the contents of header.php?  On initial inspection I don't see a loop...but wondering what is in that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if someone were to disable javascript in their browser, they could bypass your jQuery validation and send 1000 emails because you are not validating your `Reply-To` email server-side.

Try changing your server-side validation to something like:

```
$to      = 'harryfelton12@gmail.com';
$subject = 'ALERT! Website Form Submission';
$message = 'Users Name: '.strip_tags($_POST['Name'])."\n"; 
$message .= 'Users Email: '.strip_tags($_POST['Email'])."\n";
$message .= 'Submitted Message: '.strip_tags($_POST['Comment'])."\n";
$headers = 'From: noReply@harryfelton.com' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: '.strip_tags($_POST['Email']) . "\r\n";

// User the filter_var() function to check that there is no manipulation
// of the $headers
if(filter_var($_POST['Email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                console.log('Mail OK')
                location.href="/"  
            </script>
<?php   } 
   } ?>
```

I don't see any loop and from what you have posted. aside from server-side validation, I don't see any reason why it should send 1000 emails.

Comment: Hmm, Although the form isnt visible if they dont have javascript as is it shown via a javascript function in another file. Even if they were too, would I still receive a message?

Comment: As in it's hidden by a style sheet `class="hidden"`?

Comment: Yes, does that stop it from being submitted? If not then what other problem may cause this.

Comment: No because you can turn off style sheets as well so it's no longer hidden.

Comment: From your code, there doesn't appear to be anything else that would make it submit like that. If your host says they don't see anything technically wrong on their end, I am not too sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Are you using AJAX anywhere?

Comment: Can people still submit the message without JS, if so, then whats the security issue with this other than what you already pointed out? No, I have never used AJAX

Comment: People could submit the form if they turned off javascripting and style sheets in their browser but besides that one vulnerability which would definitely allow someone to send a crap load of emails off, there isn't much else on this page that looks dangerous or that would cause what's happening (mind you I am not a security expert by any means!!).

Comment: Hmmm, How is javaScript turned off any more dangerous than someone with JavaScript, at the end of the day either party could mass send email, have you got any ideas on how to allow a certain person to send an email every hour or so, like a cookie or cache file (Dont have any experience with either)

Comment: I'll try to explain it if I can. You have a validation in place that uses client scripting which can be disabled. That is to say your jQuery validation forces a valid email in that field. If the user turns off javascripting, they can then put whatever they want into that field like `bcc` or `cc` addresses. If on your server side, you have no validation, it will allow that input to go through, so it's best to validate on the server side. Client side is more of a deterrent to the average user. It doesn't truly safe-guard against hacks.

Comment: If you look at my code snippit, it uses the `filter_var()` function which will check that the email is just one email by itself, not being corrupted by other malicious code or additional email addresses.

Comment: I see, Still no reason why it would be sending mass mail, this must be the fault of 000webhost here, Even if the email input is multiple emails, Im not sending them a verification or anything, literally a string to my self, all in ONE email. Thanks for your help, when the host is back online ill add your handy filter_var(), good protection against mass mailing in the future when response emails are sent instantly

Comment: Yeah there should be no reason it sends that many emails except if it was compromised or a technical issue .

Comment: It only happens when I click send too, making me think maybe they aren't refreshing the email 'counter' meaning as soon as I send a mail it sees it as over the limit and re suspends me -_- Although my mailbox still doesnt have 1000 period, ever, at all! Strange hey. If I can get the site back up then Ill try again.

Thanks- Happy New Year